# Cómo forzar la instalación de WebLogic 12c en un jdk 1.7?

Tags: java, weblogic

Hola a todos estoy teniendo problemas con la instalación del WebLogic 12c en un jdk 1.7 y es necesario hacer está instalacion ya que el servidor de producción tiene esa configuración.

Estuve desarrollando con un jdk 1.8 y el WebLogic 12c pero el problema era al desplegar la aplicación al servidor ya que aveces marcaba errores o simplemente dejaba de funcionar el sistema y causa de esto es porque el war generado se hizo con un jdk 1.8 y en el servidor de producción tiene la 1.7.

Hay forma de forzar la instalación del  WebLogic usando jdk 1.7? Gracias espero y alguien me pueda ayudar

Comment: Tendrías además que compilar el proyecto para que funcione con 1.7

Comment: Eso hice pero igual sigue marcando errores me parece porque obtiene y empaqueta las librerías del WebLogic con jdk 1.8 y en el servidor me marca errores como el ejemplo de validación dentro de un if o codificar archivos, ya que genera errores cuando se codifica.

Comment: El título dice "instalar weblogic en JDK 7" pero de lo que hablas es de compilar y empaquetar tu proyecto en JDK 7, que son cosas bastante distintas. Pon la información de como generas y empaquetas la aplicación.

Comment: El lío con instalar Weblogic pasa además porque [te va a validar el JDK](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/wls/12c/12_2_1/02-01-004-InstallWLSInfrastructure/installweblogicinfrastructure.html). Y si es en un entorno productivo, suena a mala idea usar una versión no soportada (el classloader de Weblogic ya es un fastidio por sí solo, no imagino cambiándole el JDK)

Comment: Por cierto. Procura siempre **mostrar** los errores y no contarnos el chisme de que "a veces marcaba errores". Estás suponiendo la causa y ni siquiera sabemos si es así o no.

Comment: Alfabeto. El único error que mostraría es la salida del archivo codificado que genera un robo con un signo de interrogación. Lo cual no tiene sentido, e igual en el código. Cuando se despliega el sistema ni siquiera muestra errores de que es lo que está pasando. Por eso el motivo....

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el Universall installer [te va a validar](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/wls/12c/12_2_1/02-01-004-InstallWLSInfrastructure/installweblogicinfrastructure.html) el JDK siempre.

Trata de seguir [estos pasos](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/doc.1211/e24492/jdk7.htm#WLSIG261) documentados en Oracle para ver si te deja usar Java7. No sé si todas las opciones de 12.1 estén en 12.2 pero no se pierde nada al probar.

- Modifica el startWeblogic.sh, que puede generar líos al usar el heap correctamente para Java7:

```
# UNIX:

USER_MEM_ARGS="-Xms32m -Xmx200m -XX:MaxPermSize=350m"
export USER_MEM_ARGS

#Windows:

set USER_MEM_ARGS=-Xms32m -Xmx200m -XX:MaxPermSize=350m
```

- Trata de no usar clases en sun.*, pues no van a estar presentes y te va a arrojar classNotFoundException en tiempo de ejecución.
- JDBC 4.1 no está soportado por Java7, así que tu aplicación no debería usarlo
- Instala el JDK7 y define la variable JAVA_HOME apuntándole (a la carpeta /bin).
- Al instalar WebLogic Server: selecciona *Custom installation*. Para la selección del JDK, deselecciona las opciones del JDK incluido (bundled) y bajo la sección *Local JDK* dale a Browse y selecciona el directorio al que apuntas con JAVA_HOME.

  - En la pantalla Choose Install Type, selecciona la opción Custom.
  - En la pantalla JDK Selection, deseleccione las opciones del JDK incluido (bundled) y bajo la sección *Local JDK* dale a Browse y selecciona el directorio al que apuntas con JAVA_HOME.

Comment: Hola alfabravo no entendí donde está el ah startWeblogic.sh. ya que en la instalación del weblogic no está. Más que nada no entendí esa parte de cambiarle los parámetros

Comment: @LuisHernandez sobre qué S.O. está instalado todo en producción?

Comment: Esta levantado en Linux.

Comment: @LuisHernandez  pues entonces ese archivo debe existir en la instalación y deberás buscarlo. O revisa cómo estás iniciando Weblogic y sigue las indicaciones en el enlace que te compartí

Comment: siempre no pude instalarlo, cuando instalo el weblogic con el jdk 7 me aparece este error: Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 . y ya no puedo hacer los primeros pasos